# Checkbox - "Выбрать все" по группам

Tags: javascript, input, checkbox

Приветствую! Помогите пожалуйста решить задачу.
Чекбокс с классом **all_check**, выбирает сразу все чекбоксы с классом **checkbox**. Как сделать так чтобы при клике в секции **sec_one**, выбирались чекбоксы только из этой секции (группы), а не все сразу на странице. Тоже самое и с другими секциями (группами).

Как вариант решения это указать новые классы для каждой секции  (*all_check + checkbox, all_check2 + checkbox2, all_check3 + checkbox3*), но в данном случае приходится городить кучу дублирующего JS кода только с разными классами (на странице может быть до 15 блоков **sec_#**).

Можно ли как-то использовать один JS код. Чтобы при клике по чекбоксу **all_check**, он понимал что необходимо выбрать только чекбоксы из его секции (группы)?

Спасибо.

```
<form method="POST" action="">

    <div class="sec_one">
        <label><input class="all_check" type="checkbox" name="" value=""> Выбрать все</label>

        <label><input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="a[]" value="1"> Место для курения</label>
        <label><input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="a[]" value="2"> Wi-Fi</label>
        <label><input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="a[]" value="3"> Детское меню</label>
        <label><input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="a[]" value="4"> Детское меню</label>
    </div>

    <div class="sec_two">
        <label><input class="all_check" type="checkbox" name="" value=""> Выбрать все</label>

        <label><input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="b[]" value="1"> something 1</label>
        <label><input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="b[]" value="2"> something 2</label>
        <label><input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="b[]" value="3"> something 3</label>
        <label><input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="b[]" value="4"> something 4</label>
    </div>

    <div class="sec_three">
        <label><input class="all_check" type="checkbox" name="" value=""> Выбрать все</label>

        <label><input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="c[]" value="1"> something 1</label>
        <label><input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="c[]" value="2"> something 2</label>
        <label><input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="c[]" value="3"> something 3</label>
        <label><input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="c[]" value="4"> something 4</label>
    </div>

</form>


<script>
$(function () {
    var checkAll = $('input.all_check');
    var checkboxes = $('input.checkbox');

    checkAll.on('ifChecked ifUnchecked', function(event) {
        if (event.type == 'ifChecked') {
            checkboxes.iCheck('check');
        } else {
            checkboxes.iCheck('uncheck');
        }
    });

    checkboxes.on('ifChanged', function(event){
        if(checkboxes.filter(':checked').length == checkboxes.length) {
            checkAll.prop('checked', 'checked');
        } else {
            checkAll.removeProp('checked');
        }
        checkAll.iCheck('update');
    });

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно искать предка и переключать в его области все боксы:

```js
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.all_check')).forEach(e => e.addEventListener('change', handler)); // Назначаем слушатель

function handler(e){
  // Выбираем все боксы из... дедушки и ставим их в нужное состояние
  Array.from(this.parentNode.parentNode.querySelectorAll('.checkbox')).forEach(e => e.checked = this.checked);
}
```

```html
<form method="POST" action="">

    <div class="sec_one">
        <label><input class="all_check" type="checkbox" name="" value=""> Выбрать все</label>

        <label><input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="a[]" value="1"> Место для курения</label>
        <label><input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="a[]" value="2"> Wi-Fi</label>
        <label><input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="a[]" value="3"> Детское меню</label>
        <label><input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="a[]" value="4"> Детское меню</label>
    </div>

    <div class="sec_two">
        <label><input class="all_check" type="checkbox" name="" value=""> Выбрать все</label>

        <label><input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="b[]" value="1"> something 1</label>
        <label><input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="b[]" value="2"> something 2</label>
        <label><input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="b[]" value="3"> something 3</label>
        <label><input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="b[]" value="4"> something 4</label>
    </div>

    <div class="sec_three">
        <label><input class="all_check" type="checkbox" name="" value=""> Выбрать все</label>

        <label><input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="c[]" value="1"> something 1</label>
        <label><input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="c[]" value="2"> something 2</label>
        <label><input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="c[]" value="3"> something 3</label>
        <label><input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="c[]" value="4"> something 4</label>
    </div>

</form>
```

Comment: Большое спасибо